# Ubuntu Server on-line manual incomplete

Tags: 18.04, server, manpage

I've realized that `man` in Ubuntu Server (Bionic) is incomplete if compared with Ubuntu Desktop (Bionic) version.

I searched for some system calls like `fork` using the command `man 2 fork` and it return `No manual entry for fork in section 2`.

This doesn't happen on Ubuntu Desktop version.

What I would have to do for get a complete version of the manual on Ubuntu Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sudo apt install manpages-dev`

The `manpages-dev` package includes over 2000 additional manpages...including fork.